# AD Graph API Sign in Reports

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am currently attempting to pull sign in data from both an Office365 E5 trial account, and also an office365 developer account via the Windows graph api, as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-reporting-api-sign-in-activity-reference and I am currently getting the following error back:

```json
{
  "odata.error": {
    "code": "Authentication_RequestFromNonPremiumTenantOrB2CTenant",
    "message": {
      "lang": "en",
      "value": "Api request is not from premium licensed tenant or b2c tenant"
    },
    "requestId": "905d2565-30f5-4554-932e-273f5117199e",
    "date": "2017-05-25 06:55:33Z"
  }
}
```

Is it possible to get this information from the API without having to sign up to a premium Active Directory subscription?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is looking for a way to do this for a developer/trial account for free, I ended up using the Azure AD trial in order to retrieve the sign in data.

Answer (score 1):

No ,refer to [Azure Active Directory sign-in activity report API reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-reporting-api-getting-started)(Prerequisites section):

> > Prerequisites
> >
> > To access this report through the reporting API, you must have:
> >
> > 1.An Azure Active Directory Premium P1 or P2 edition
> >
> > 2.Completed the prerequisites to access the Azure AD reporting API.

So you need Azure Active Directory Premium P1 or P2 edition to call sign-in activity report API .